# The positive sequence: $a_{n+1} =\sqrt{1 + \frac{a^{2}_{n}}{4}}$. Is strictly increasing and bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds, monotone-functions

How can I prove that this positive sequence, with $0 \leq a_{0} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$:

$a_{n+1} =\sqrt{1 + \frac{a^{2}_{n}}{4}}$ is strictly increasing and bounded above?

Comment: It's always easier to solve problems like this if you work out what the upper bound is.  You can get that just by trying an example.

Comment: @lulu the upper bound is in some sense already given by the bound on $a_0$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  I agree, though I am not sure this is clear to the OP.

Comment: As you are not a new member by any means, I will admit I find it strange that this question was upvoted twice so soon and that many of your other questions are also problem statement questions. This question is not spectacularly special, so I don't see it earning itself interest. Where did you get this problem? What have you tried? For example, you very recently asked a similar question concerning whether a recurrence was increasing and bounded, so I would expect you to at least try something here. Even writing out the first few values of $a_n$ works (there's a pattern).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Im sorry. I will elaborate my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bounded:** We need to show that for any $n \ge 0$, $0 \le a_n < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. This can be done by induction. Our base case is given in the prompt. Now assume that $0 \le a_k < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. Then
$$0 \le a_k < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \implies 0< 1\le\sqrt{1 + \frac{a_k^2}{4}} <\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3}}= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
Therefore, $0 \le a_{k+1} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. Therefore, the induction hypothesis holds and $0 \le a_n < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ for any $n \ge 0$.

**Strictly increasing:** Show that $a_{n+1} > a_n$. By applying the definition of $a_{n+1}$,
$$a_{n+1} =\sqrt{1 + \frac{a_n^2}{4}} >a_n \underset{a_n\ge0}{\iff} 1+\frac{a_n^2}{4} > a_n^2 \iff \frac{3a_n^2}{4}<1 \underset{a_n\ge0}{\iff} a_n <\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
Therefore, $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing.

Therefore, $\{a_n\}$ is convergent. Let $a_n \to L$ as $n \to \infty$. Then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{1 + \frac{a_n^2}{4}} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{L^2}{4}} = L \implies L = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: You can figure out what $L$ should be as follows. If you assume that $a_n \to L$, then $L =\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{L^2}{4}} \implies L^2=1+\dfrac{L^2}{4}\implies L = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt 3}$

Comment: @HiMatt I have a question. Why $\sqrt{1 + \frac{a^{2}_{k}}{4}} < \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{3}}$?

Comment: Hi @Laura, $a_k < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, so plug in $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ in for $a_k$  in the equation you stated and you get your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By induction $a_n < \frac  2 {\sqrt 3}$ for all $n$ and this implies $a_n^{2} <1+\frac  {a_n^{2}} 4$ which gives $a_n <a_{n+1}$.